# Eclipse 2021-3 C/C++ Skipping Breakpoints

Tags: c, eclipse, gdb

I have looked as thoroughly as I can, and I have found no solution to my issue. I'm on RHEL 8 using the C/C++ Eclipse IDE v2021-3 and while my IDE once stopped at breakpoints, it no longer does so. So my experience is that it simply runs through to completion as if a normal Run was performed, regardless of where I place my breakpoints.

Things I have tried that have not worked:

- Ensuring that `Skip All Breakpoints` is disabled
- Cleaning and rebuilding the project
- Ensuring that my breakpoints are attached to code that is being executed
- Ensuring that Eclipse is up to date.
- Restarting Eclipse
- Crying
- Updating `gdb`

Things I have not tried:

- Redownloading Eclipse, since it isn't installed on my machine, and it's freshly updated, I didn't do this

Any thoughts? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you tried it on a different project, such as "hello.c"?

Comment: I have not, @stark, let me try that

Comment: That did work! I'm not sure how to use this information, though

Comment: Set a breakpoint at `main` so it is impossible to skip and see if that works.

Comment: Setting a breakpoint at main or within main did not work! It just passed by the breakpoints as it had been. Must be isolated to this project which is interesting

Comment: Set to Debug mode and not Release mode?

Comment: Do I just need to compile with `-g` for that? if so, it didn't appear to change anything